# How to redirect to another HTML page after submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page containing a form element. Form contains input of type radio and a button at the end. I want that when button is clicked, a javascript method be called which gets the value of selected choice and redirect to selectedChoice.html page.

Here is my HTML page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="../js/navigation.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chooseBodyPart">
            <form>
                <div class="question-text">
                    <p>Which body part is at dis-ease??</p>
                </div>
                <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="chest"> Chest <br>
                <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="head"> Head <br>
                <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="shoulders"> Shoulders <br>
                <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="eyes"> Eyes <br>
                <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="ears"> Ears <br>
                <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="heart"> Heart <br>
                <button onclick="redirectToNextPageBasedOnResponse();">Proceed</button>
            </form>



        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And below is my js.

```
function getListOfChoices(form) {
    var choices = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
    return choices;
}


// list of choices should be passed to this method and name of checked choice should be returned.
// In case no choice is selected the return null
function getNameOfCheckedChoice(choices) {
    var selectedChoice = null;
    for (var choiceNumber = 0; choiceNumber < choices.length; choiceNumber++) {
        if (choices[choiceNumber].checked) {
            selectedChoice = choices[choiceNumber].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    return selectedChoice;
}


function redirectToNextPageBasedOnResponse() {
    var divContainingForm = document.getElementById("chooseBodyPart");
    var form = divContainingForm.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    var choices = getListOfChoices(form);
    var selectedChoice = getNameOfCheckedChoice(choices);

    window.location.href = "http://" + window.location.host + "/html/" + selectedChoice + ".html";
}
```

Working of code is exactly as i want but once control returns from redirectToNextPageBasedOnResponse(), URL does not change to what I coded , instead a query param is inserted in the existing URL with value equal to selected choice.

Can someone please explain what is happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing only one thing. Calling [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the submit event.

You need to take the event via `onclick="redirectToNextPageBasedOnResponse(event);"` and then in your handler, do `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
function getListOfChoices(form) {
  var choices = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
  return choices;
}


// list of choices should be passed to this method and name of checked choice should be returned.
// In case no choice is selected the return null
function getNameOfCheckedChoice(choices) {
  var selectedChoice = null;
  for (var choiceNumber = 0; choiceNumber < choices.length; choiceNumber++) {
    if (choices[choiceNumber].checked) {
      selectedChoice = choices[choiceNumber].value;
      break;
    }
  }
  return selectedChoice;
}


function redirectToNextPageBasedOnResponse(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var divContainingForm = document.getElementById("chooseBodyPart");
  var form = divContainingForm.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
  var choices = getListOfChoices(form);
  var selectedChoice = getNameOfCheckedChoice(choices);

  window.location.href = "http://" + window.location.host + "/html/" + selectedChoice + ".html";
}
```

```html
<div id="chooseBodyPart">
  <form>
    <div class="question-text">
      <p>Which body part is at dis-ease??</p>
    </div>
    <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="chest"> Chest <br>
    <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="head"> Head <br>
    <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="shoulders"> Shoulders <br>
    <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="eyes"> Eyes <br>
    <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="ears"> Ears <br>
    <input class="radio-option" type="radio" name="bodyPartAtDisease" value="heart"> Heart <br>
    <button onclick="redirectToNextPageBasedOnResponse(event);">Proceed</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

So, we prevent the default behaviour of the form submit and add our own custom behaviour to it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was stuck since yesterday.
Also IDE showed that event is deprecated. Anything on this??

Comment: It's not deprecated, AFAIK. What is the deprecation message that shows up?

Comment: `Deprecated symbol used. Consult docs for better understanding.`

Comment: I'm not sure. It's the common way to access event in inline event handlers. Maybe your IDE wants you to use `addEventListener` or there is some extension that's wrongly identifying something.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Please check

```
window.location=url
```

or

```
history.pushState({}, "title", url);
```

instead.